# Custom Chatter Feed

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter, chatter-feed, connect-api

Trying to build a lightning component or VF page wherein I can quickly see below views of chatters, is there something nearby already available on AppExchange or Github?

- List of all unread chatters (Lightning notification isn't that great in that matter, as you need to scroll to read each unread chat).
- List of all chatters where I have been mentioned and I've not replied
- List of all chatters where I have chattered to User X and X haven't replied yet

If not, what objects do I query to find the above information?

Comment: Did you look at connectAPI of salesforce?

Comment: Yes. We did look at the Connect API and its classes (ChatterMessage & ChatterFeeds) but it wasn't that fruitful. We looked at the methods like ConnectApi.UnreadConversationCount as described in the documentation of ChatterMessage but it is always returning 0 value. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ChiragMehta are you sending Chatter private messages? The UnreadConversationCount is for PM/DM. It won't describe how many chatter message you've seen since last check. 

The bullet points your asking for aren't provided by any out-of-the-box SFDC/Chatter API's I've seen, you'd likely have to construct a custom query/apex yourself. You can do something similar with FeedItem/FeedComment, but I imagine it'd be computationally ineffecient.

Comment: Yes, I too realized that the unread count I shared is for DM, so it is not helpful for chatter notifications. Coming to my requirements, I was looking to build one but looks like aren't provided by any out-of-the-box SFDC/Chatter APIs. Building totally custom will be another challenge and computationally inefficient (as u said).